# Servicehost throwing an error, even though added to configuration with netsh

Tags: wcf, service, servicehost, netsh

`ServiceHost.Open()` is throwing this error:

> HTTP could not register URL http://+:8001/. Your process does not have
>   access rights to this namespace (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).

So I used **netsh** to add the url. But event though it is added, i'm still getting the error. This is the command I use:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8001/ user=djerryy`

`djerryy` is my computername. When I run netsh http show urlacl i see it was added.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the name of the user account who is running the service. Here's a couple of options:

- Local user account:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8001/ user=ComputerName\Username
```

- Domain user account:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8001/ user=DomainName\Username
```

- Built-in NetworkService account:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8001/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Comment: i'm not in a domain.
and i tried DJERRYY\Djerry, which still gave me the same error

Comment: Where are you hosting your service? Do you start it from Visual Studio? What is the service endpoint?

Comment: No, the service was installed with a setup project. It runs form windows services. This is the address i'm using as Uri : "net.tcp://localhost:8000", but i also tries adding 8000...

Comment: That URL does not use HTTP as transport protocol. It uses TCP, so you shouldn't get that error. Shouldn't it be "http://localhost:8001" instead? Also, under which user account is the Windows Service running?

Comment: you've lost me now: this (net.tcp://localhost:8000) isn't used in commands if i understand you correctly, it is the setup of my server (this link shows my setup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847097/how-to-restart-a-wcf-server-from-within-a-client)
the service is running as a network service, and i'm logged in as "djerry", which should be administrator.

Comment: You need to grant access to the HTTP URL to the NetworkService account. I updated my answer with the correct command.

Comment: at last, servicehost opened. Now to get my client connected again... :)

Answer (score 5):

I must stress:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8001/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"`

will work only on a system with the English locale!

A better way is to remove that one space and make it:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8001/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE"`

Now the command will work on any locale. I spent a good 0,5h battling this today... all because of a single char. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To add even more to this answer: You **MUST** specify a port number! Spend quite a while trying to authorize a service to bind to a normal HTTP address, it only started working when I explicitly specified:

```
netsh http add urlacl 
    url=http://some.example.com:80/extension/ 
    user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE"
```